# Difference Between Printing &object and object in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c

What's the difference between doing `NSLog(@"%p", &object);` and `NSLog(@"%p", object);`?

Both appear to print out a memory address but I'm not sure which one is the actually memory address of the object.

Comment: The first prints the memory address of the pointer `object`.  The second prints the value of the pointer `object`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I like to imagine it:

You can think of memory as a continuous strip that has addresses for each usable chunk.

```
NSObject *a = nil;
NSObject *b = nil;

                                  b         a
                                  v         v
+---------+---------+--,   ,-+---------+---------+
|         |         | /   /  | 0x0     | 0x0     |
+---------+---------+-`   `--+---------+---------+
     ^         ^                  ^         ^
  0x05aa2   0x05aaa            0x07bf0   0x07bf8

NSLog(@"%p %p", b, &b); //=> 0x0 0x07bf0
```

We have two local variable of type `NSObject *`. Both are assigned `nil` so there contents are `0x0`. You can see that both of these variable themselves have a memory address `0x07bf0` and `0x07bf8`.

Then if we create an instance of an object and throw that into the mix we get

```
NSObject *a = nil;
NSObject *b = [[NSObject alloc] init];

           [NSObject]             b         a
               v                  v         v
+---------+---------+--,   ,-+---------+---------+
|         | ******* | /   /  | 0x05aaa | 0x0     |
+---------+---------+-`   `--+---------+---------+
     ^         ^                  ^         ^
  0x05aa2   0x05aaa            0x07bf0   0x07bf8
               ^                  /
                \                /
                 `--------------'

NSLog(@"%p %p", b, &b); //=> 0x05aaa 0x07bf0
```

We have the same local variables declared as before except now there is an instance of `NSObject` that is being pointed to by `b`.

As the type is `NSObject *` we know we have a pointer to an object so when you do `NSLog(@"%p", b);` you are getting the result of going to the memory address `b` and then taking the memory address in it's contents and following that to the `NSObject` for which you then print it's memory address. When you do `&b` you are essentially just doing the first step and asking for the memory address of the storage for the actual variable `b`.

You should be able to see how these memory addresses relate to each other

Comment: Wow, such answer, much love.

Answer (score 2):

Variables that point to objects are always pointers in Objective-C, so I'm assuming `object` is a pointer (wouldn't make much sense to print it with the `%p` flag if it wasn't). In the first case, you are getting the address of where the *pointer* exists in memory; in the second, the address of where the *object itself* exists in memory.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage is `NSLog(@"%p", object)`. I set up an example:

```
NSObject *object = nil;
NSLog(@"%p", &object); // prints 0x7fff535d7bf8
NSLog(@"%p", object);  // prints 0x0
```

From this, you can clearly see that the latter is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing that it means in C. `&object` is a pointer to the object variable. `object` is (perhaps) a pointer to something else, but it is typically the contents of the `object` variable.